# how to select value from json file which find another value matches use jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, select, jq

I have been struggling with json stuff. I want to find running state's href. How can I do that with `jq` or another like `bash`-style?

Here is my curl output:

```
{
  "relations": {
    "total": 9,
    "link": [
      {
        "href": "https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/",
        "rel": "up"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/executions/",
        "rel": "add"
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "value": "8f961082-cccc-412f-9244-16ba5b949dbe",
            "name": "id"
          },
          {
            "value": "2019-09-28T17:20:40.691-01:00",
            "name": "startDate"
          },
          {
            "value": "2019-09-28T17:20:43.949-01:00",
            "name": "endDate"
          },
          {
            "value": "completed",
            "name": "state"
          },
          {
            "value": "test",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "name": "currentItemDisplayName"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/executions/8f961082-cccc-412f-9244-16ba5b949dbe/",
        "rel": "down"
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "value": "b28832cb-2a97-4ec8-848f-35fec95eb867",
            "name": "id"
          },
          {
            "value": "2019-09-28T17:21:04.643-01:00",
            "name": "startDate"
          },
          {
            "value": "running",
            "name": "state"
          },
          {
            "value": "test",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "name": "currentItemDisplayName"
          }
        ],
        "href": "https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/executions/b28832cb-2a97-4ec8-848f-35fec95eb867/",
        "rel": "down"
      }
}
```

If I talk with example I want to find href key is https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/executions/b28832cb-2a97-4ec8-848f-35fec95eb867/ by way of running key.

Comment: Please display the output you want.

Comment: `running state's href` - what does that mean and what is it?

Comment: `parse error: Objects must consist of key:value pairs at line 67, column 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the sample JSON has been fixed, the following jq query:

```
   .relations.link[]
   | select( has("attributes") )
   | select( any(.attributes[]; .value=="running" and .name == "state") )
   | .href
```

produces:

```
"https://vro:8281/vco/api/workflows/6433f56f-13b7-46a7-a9ec-a3e38c7ff69d/executions/b28832cb-2a97-4ec8-848f-35fec95eb867/"
```

### In two lines (i.e., with one pipe)

```
.relations.link[]
| select(any(.attributes[]?; .value=="running" and .name == "state")).href
```